# Django: how to get Foreign key id?

Tags: python, django, model, foreign-keys

I have 2 models as below

```
class Product(models.Model):
   product_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   product_weight = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class ProductImage(models.Model):
   product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
   image = models.ImageField(upload_to='/images/{product_id}/', blank=True)
```

How to extract product_id in ProductImage model?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show your code where you need the id?

Comment: I want to save image in directory of product_id

Answer (score 15):

You can get the "raw" value of any foreign key in Django by adding "_id" to the field name

```
obj = ProductImage.objects.get()
obj.product_id  # Will return the id of the related product
```

You can also just follow the relationship but this will perform another DB lookup if the relationship has not been cached by using something like `select_related`

```
obj.product.id
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I have tried so far and found the solution. The only option I found for achieving is using pre_save and post_save signals. And here is how I achieved the solution. If anyone has different solution, please share. Thanks.

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

_UNSAVED_IMAGEFIELD = 'unsaved_imagefield'

def upload_path_handler(instance, filename):
    import os.path
    fn, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    return "images/{id}/{fname}".format(id=instance.product_id, 
    fname=filename)

class ProductImage(models.Model):
   product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
   image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_path_handler, blank=True)

@receiver(pre_save, sender=ProductImage)
def skip_saving_file(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if not instance.pk and not hasattr(instance, _UNSAVED_IMAGEFIELD):
        setattr(instance, _UNSAVED_IMAGEFIELD, instance.image)
        instance.image = None

@receiver(post_save, sender=ProductImage)
def update_file_url(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created and hasattr(instance, _UNSAVED_IMAGEFIELD):
        instance.image = getattr(instance, _UNSAVED_IMAGEFIELD)
        instance.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add str function in your foreign reference model Product.

```
class Product(models.Model):
  product_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  product_weight = models.CharField(max_length=30)

  def __str__(self):
      return str(self.id)
```